# Convert pandas series cell to string and datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, datetime64

I have sliced the pandas dataframe.

```
end_date = df[-1:]['end'] 

type(end_date) 
Out[4]: pandas.core.series.Series 

end_date 
Out[3]: 
48173   2017-09-20 04:47:59 
Name: end, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

1. How to get rid of end_date's index value `48173` and get only `2017-09-20 04:47:59` string? I have to call REST API with `2017-09-20 04:47:59` as a parameter, so I have to get string from pandas `datetime64` series.
2. How to get rid of end_date's index value `48173` and get only datetime object [something like `datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-09-20 04:47:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`]. I need it because, later I will have to check if `'2017-09-20 04:47:59' < datetime.datetime(2017,1,9)`

I need to convert just a single cell value, not a whole column.
How to do these conversions?

Comment: Please separate your code from the execution in the interpreter, as it is unclear.

Comment: `df[-1:]['a'].item()` or `df[-1:]['a'].values[0]`?

Comment: This works. Thanks.

Comment: I am confused. 

`import pandas as pd  
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=5, freq='T'), columns=['end'])  

df[-1:]['end']  
4   2017-01-01 00:04:00  
Name: end, dtype: datetime64[ns]  

df['end'].iloc[-1]  
Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:04:00')`  


The line before last line returns index and datetime64 but last line returns Timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you need:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['2017-09-20 04:47:59','2017-10-20 04:47:59','2017-09-30 04:47:59']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['end'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
df
```

`df` will be:

```
    end
0   2017-09-20 04:47:59
1   2017-10-20 04:47:59
2   2017-09-30 04:47:59
```

After that you can use below code to get rid of index and use as 'Timestamp' object:

```
end_date = df['end'].iloc[-1] #get last row of column end
print(type(end_date)) # pandas.tslib.Timestamp
end_date_str = end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #convert to str
print(end_date_str) # '2017-09-30 04:47:59'
print(end_date < datetime.datetime(2017,1,9)) #False
```

Comment: @user3225309 glad it helps, if it is the right solution, please mark as an accept answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply cast the result to a string, and recover it using `.values[0]`:

```
In [38]: end_date
Out[38]:
48173   2017-09-20 04:47:59
Name: end, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [39]: end_date.astype(str).values[0]
Out[39]: '2017-09-20 04:47:59'
```

If you want a datetime object, you have to convert it to a timestamp, and then back to a `datetime` object:

```
In [42]: end_date.values[0].item()
Out[42]: 1505882879000000000

In [43]: datetime.fromtimestamp(end_date.values[0].item()/10**9)
Out[43]: datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 6, 47, 59)
```

Otherwise, you can `strptime` the string recovered in step 1:

```
In [48]: datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date.astype(str).values[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[48]: datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 20, 4, 47, 59)
```

You may wonder why there is a **2 hours difference** between the results. This is because the [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) takes my timezone into account (currently CEST, which is UTC+2).
On the other hand, parsing a string to a `datetime` object doesn't yield any timezone information, `srtptime` naively parses the timestamp without regards for the timezone, which leads to a 2 hours discrepancy.

Comment: end_date.astype(str).values[0] works. Thanks. But
np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.utcnow()).astype(datetime)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-25-e8410bf10501>", line 1, in <module>
    np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.utcnow()).astype(datetime)
TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date.astype(str).values[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') works as well.

Comment: @user3225309 what are you trying to achieve in your first comment ? Convert directly to datetime ? You can't cast directly through pandas, abd have to refer to the answer I linked.
Moreover, if it solves your problem, feel free to "accept the answer"

Comment: On link you have provided I found the following:
np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.utcnow()).astype(datetime)

which doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @user3225309 sorry, I didn't notice you were using a `datetime64[ns]` and not a `datetime64`. I updated my answer to match that.